# How can I retrieve the PDO error message?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm just converting a site to PDO and this is my first exposure to it, but I'm having difficulty obtaining any kind of useful error information from PDO. I've read numerous other posts on this subject but none of them seem to provide a solution which works for me.

Here is the code:

```
try {
    $dbh    = new PDO("mysql:host=".CO_DB_HOST.";dbname=".CO_DB_NAME, CO_DB_UNAME, CO_DB_PWORD);

    $dbh    ->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


function addRec($data) {

    global $part_id, $dbh;
    $part_id++;

    try {
        $sth=$dbh->prepare("
            INSERT INTO 
                non_existent_table
                (
                    name
                ) VALUES (
                    ?
                );
        ");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            $sth->execute($data[$i]);
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Something went wrong. Please report this error.";
        file_put_contents('/PDOErrors.txt', PDOStatement::errorInfo(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

// Insert a database record
$data = array(
        array(
            'joe blogs',    /* name */
        )
);
addRec($data);
```

The table does not exist but I'm getting no error in PDOError.txt and nothing in my httpd error log. Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks.

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) is **not** a static method. Also, it returns an array, not a string.

You should be fine with the information in the exception. Use something like this instead

```
file_put_contents('/PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
```

For extra information, you could also append the [stacktrace](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php).

**Edit**

Are you sure `/PDOErrors.txt` is the correct file path for your error log? That's in the filesystem root which I doubt is what you want or even possible.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I was using getMessage() previously and have now changed back to it as it seems like the best option, however, still no error message (except for the echo).

Good point about the file path although I would expect to get an error in my apache log about that? How would I specify a path in the root of the site please without using a server specific file path (for portability)?

Also, please can you elaborate on how I can append the 'stacktrace' you mentioned?

Comment: I figured out the path issue and changed the line to:

    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);

But unfortunately still no error message in the file and nothing in the server log, such as "Can't open file".

Comment: I've just added "$e->getMessage()" into the echo statement and it appears to be empty which I guess explains why it's not being written to the file (now the file path is correct) - but why is it empty?